# clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++

Tags: ios, clang, cocoapods

I am install Box2d using cocoa pod to use box2d. Everything is working good but xcode throwing this below error. I took a screenshot. take a look.

[image]

Comment: Continue reading... "requires iOS 5.0 or later"...

Comment: yes, but i my deployment target is 6.0.

Comment: What's the development sysroot that the compiler sees?

Comment: Where we can find sysroot?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know, since I don't use Xcode. If there's some sort of facility to see the compiler invocation, it will be included there (`-iysroot <whatever>`).

Comment: In Xcode, we have to only set deployment target. system root is not related to Xcode, otherwise mac would not allow to install Xcode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41757/discussion-between-romit-mewada-and-h2co3)

Comment: @RomitMewada The "Base SDK" build setting will determine sysroot. Currently, it's set to iOS7, which is OK. It *should* always be the newest SDK.

Comment: The minimum iOS version which has included clang's Standard C++ library is iOS 5. That means, the deployment target of the target "Pods-box2d" shall be set >= iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have select Default LLVM Copiler[image]